# How to get C++ function descriptions using Company?

Tags: company-mode, irony-mode, rtags

Forgive me if this isn't a feature which is easily available through some emacs package. I'm using Emacs for C++ development with Company, RTags, and Irony. When choosing a company completion candidate, I would like a description of what the candidate (presumably function) actually does; either in pos-tip or in a new buffer, it doesn't really matter.

For example, if I were to write:

```
    std::string my_string;
    my_string.push_back
```

I would expect a buffer or pos-tip to display a description of what the member function `push_back` actually does, e.g., the description which can be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/. Currently, the best I can get is a description of the argument types that push_back expects.

Thanks for taking the time to help.